# What does the sharp (#) means in rundll32.exe parameters

Tags: windows, rundll32

For example:

```
rundll32.exe "test.dll",#1
```

I looked into rundll32.exe [manual](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/164787)

But I can not find the meaning of the sharp(#).

Comment: You'd normally provide the *name* of the function in test.dll that you want to run.  By using #, you tell it that you don't want to specify the name but the number of the exported function.  First one in this case.  Using the name is of course best, less accidents that way.

Comment: @HansPassant You don't always have a choice. Functions can be exported by ordinal only.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Then fix your DLL to export it by name. Exporting by ordinals means that rundll32 cannot determine what character set your function expects to receive (because rundll32 infers that from whether the function name ends in A or W).

Answer (score 5):

Using the sharp sign instead of a function name in the parameters to `rundll32.exe` is used for calling an exported function by its Ordinal instead of its name.

Please see
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264882(v=vs.60).aspx for more information.